# Reference Application for JPA entity usage patterns

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

Is there a large real world open source project with many JPA entities defined. Something that could illustrate best JPA practices for defining JPA entities?

All the samples I find are so small or focused.

I'm struggling, to find anything on what the accepted "good practices" are. For example how best to :

- add/removing entities in relationships(do I provide support for this type of thing on the entity?)
- For one2one, should I return null from the getter if its empty, throw, or provide an API to check isEmpty()
- do I do these thing's on the entity class, or proivde some type of helper?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great open source eCommerce reference app called Broadleaf eCommerce. Its available on GitHub https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce. It's has a substanital JPA domain model and they are using Hibernate.

I'm finding it a great resource for learning JPA & Hibernate